# insertmultiple check box value

Tags: php, html

```
<html> 
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="custopt[1]" value="Option1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="custopt[2]" value="Option2"/>
</body>
</html>


    <?php
     $custopt = (\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'custopt'));

     for($x=1;$i<=2;$x++)
     {
if(empty($custopt[$x])
{
  /*    DO NOT INSERT */
}
 else
 {    /* @var $sql type */

     $sql="insert into starterveg(itemId,title,subtitle,descript,availability,price,customoption,r1,r2)values
     ('$itemId','$title','$subtitle','$descript','$availability','$price','$custopt[$x]','$r1','$r2')";

     /* @var $result type */
     $result= \mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql) or die(\mysqli_error($dbhandle));
     /* @var $custop type */

     }}
   ?>
```

I have an issue,the checkbox field is empty in the database,i need the corresponding values of the checked boxes to get stored. Now i have updated the code. Now im getting the O/P as **success connect samples success**

Comment: what is `<boby?` ????

Comment: Input elements should wrap around `<form>` tag.

Comment: @krishna you can understand.. its <body> its a typo anyone can understand.. dont find typo focus on the concern..!

Comment: @DeepakSharma sometimes typo cause you errors which you cannot find.

Comment: its <body> i have just given the sample code of html to show my checkbox tag

Comment: @krishna did u ever try in html page without html tag and body tag it works.. if not then try it now..

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have your checkbox listed dynamically in a loop. If that so, try this:

```
$counter=1;

while( /* your condition */){

echo "<input type='checkbox' id='c1' name='custopt[]' value='Option1'/>
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$counter' name='hiddencounter'>";

$counter=$counter+1;

}
```

And when submitted:

```
$getcount=$_POST['hiddencounter'];
$custopt=$_POST['custopt'];

for($x=1;$x<=$getcount;$x++){

if(empty($custopt[$x])){
  /* DO NOT INSERT */
}

else {
mysqli_query($dbhandle,"INSERT INTO starterveg (itemId, title, subtitle, descript, availability, price, customoption, r1, r2)
VALUES
('$itemId','$title','$subtitle','$descript','$availability','$price','$custopt[$x]','$r1','$r2')";
}    

} /* END OF FOR LOOP */
```

**UPDATE:**

HTML file:

```
<form action='your.php' method='POST'>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="custopt[0]" value="Option1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="custopt[1]" value="Option2"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

your.PHP file:

```
$custopt=$_POST['custopt'];

for($x=0;$x<=1;$x++){

        if(empty($custopt[$x])){
          /* DO NOT INSERT */
        }

        else {
        mysqli_query($dbhandle,"INSERT INTO starterveg (itemId, title, subtitle, descript, availability, price, customoption, r1, r2)
        VALUES
        ('$itemId','$title','$subtitle','$descript','$availability','$price','$custopt[$x]','$r1','$r2')";
        }    

        } /* END OF FOR LOOP */
```

Comment: what condition should be given inside the while loop..??

Comment: Oh, okay. Are your checkboxes fix in numbers or are they generated dynamically?

Comment: i have a seperate html file in that i have my controls,in php file i have to write code to insert the checked values into the database

Comment: $select= \mysqli_select_db($dbhandle,"sample")
         or mysqli_error($dbhandle); /*select db */then i hv declred all the required variables. after this when i insert the for($x=1;$x<=2;x++) the output is samples success(connection statement is given prior to the select statement)

Comment: Try storing into your $dbhandle your whole connection, including the DB. $dbhandle=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","username","password");

Comment: $dbhandle = \mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo"success connect"; /* i hv given like this only */

Comment: Study first your connection. And why do you always incorporate your code with \ ? Go and study, boy. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: i'm using net beans IDE if i give mysqli_connect it says : fix name to mysqli_connect when i press enter it will be \mysqli_connect

Comment: i have all my connections right it is executing in the right manner. i have issue only with the insertion of checkbox value

Comment: Pl help me out in the checkbox issue im facing .I think the for loop does not gets executed.

Comment: I have given you a working code. Try updating your post, and try to put your whole code in it.

Comment: Change your for loop condition into for($x=1;$x<=2;$x++)